# How does DuckDuckGo generates Tracking Cookie and Ads

Tags: ads, tracking, duckduckgo, cookies

Despite turning off **Advertisements** in [Other Settings](https://duckduckgo.com/settings) from DuckDuckGo website, it still leaves tracking cookies and ads.

Here are the results from IObit software

1. Here is a snapshot of tracking cookie

[image]

2. Here is a snapshot of all the ads collected from Firefox browser

[image]

3. Here is a snapshot of the ads displayed from the search engine after searching from Firefox browser

[image]

4. Here is a snapshot from DuckDuckGo ad-on

### [image]

Does DuckDuckGo really protect our privacy? What kind of cookies and ads does DuckDuckGo leave that were displayed from the above screenshots attached? Are there any ways to disable them?